# Application Restart API not restarting failed application

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, application-restart, windows-api-code-pack

I'm trying to use the application restart services in `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.ApplicationServices`, however the restart isn't working.  When the application quits due to an unhandled exception it isn't restarted.  I've tried with both a Click Once install and as a stand alone EXE (no installer), running on Windows 8.

I'm using the following code to register for the restart:

```
ApplicationRestartRecoveryManager.RegisterForApplicationRestart(new RestartSettings(string.Empty,
                                                                                            RestartRestrictions.None));
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my problem.  In my tests of application restart, I was terminating the application too soon after launch.

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> Windows Error Reporting (WER) will restart your application if it has
>   been running for **at least 60 seconds** before becoming unresponsive or
>   encountering an unhandled exception.